# How to add multiple generic type constraints in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following declaration:

```
 TableViewDataSource
     <Model: ManagedObject, Cell: UITableViewCell where Cell: ConfigurableCell> :
       NSObject, UITableViewDataSource
```

I want to put a constraint on the Model type. Something like this:

```
TableViewDataSource
  <Model: ManagedObject where Model: ManagedObjectType,  
   Cell: UITableViewCell where Cell: ConfigurableCell> : 
      NSObject, UITableViewDataSource
```

How can I do that in Swift 2.0?

Comment: What specifically is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it like this instead,

```
TableViewDataSource
  <Model:ManagedObject, Cell: UITableViewCell 
     where Model:ManagedObjectType, Cell:ConfigurableCell>:  
       NSObject,UITableViewDataSource
```

All generic types should to be first declared separated with delimeter(comma) and then constraints should be provided later and each constraint also should be separated with comma. All the constraints has to be fulfilled in order for it to work.